# How to read json data value to highchart series data in angularjs the value get from an excel file to json

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have following JSON array which is generated at run-time to pass value to the Highcharts series:

```
$scope.highchartsNG = {      
    options: {
        chart: {

            type: 'spline'
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
                text: 'Year'
            },
            categories: [
                '2011',
                '2012',
                '2013',
                '2014',
                '2015',
                '2016'               
            ]

        },
        yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{}],


    title: {
        text: 'LineChart'
    },
    loading: false,

}
```

I want to pass this data to above series data dynamically:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "earnings.php",
    cache: false,
    type: 'json'
}).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);  //this data value
    $scope.series[0].setData( data[0][0][data] );
}).error(function(data){
    alert('Error Retriving informatioon');
});
```

here is my earnings.php file:

```
[["Cake Earnings",100.5,415,355,350,110,260,255,244,288,300,200,100,2,1,78,50,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["PG Earnings",450,460,480,420,425,465,475,495,412,400,500,600,2,50,79,50,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],["google Earnings",650,655,699,677,678,689,623,635,655,700,800,900,2,60,98,60,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]
```

These data callback from xlsx file using php.

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question as it's quite confusing right now, I think.

Comment: Please add some example on how would you like to pass this data.

Comment: ajax json data value to read in highchart series  array